# Running commands inside Docker Container

Tags: linux, containers, docker

I created a docker container (debian:jessie) inside a fedora 21 vm(running on vmware fusion). first time when i entered vm and ran commands it works fine. i exit the vm and start again and attach to it ( docker start -a dev-001) and run few commands they just hung. not able to find the root cause any one has any clue ? i am able to successfully enter/attach the container but simple command like ps just gets hung.

any suggestions ?

Comment: I found the problem. i should run with -i when using docker start also.

Comment: This helped me strangely even though I could have sworn I used this exact same command and it wasn't starting my container for me. Maybe I got it confused for `docker run`.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to execute commands in an running container with [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec). This allows you to execute command even when the container is started in detached mode. If you want to run just some commands and then close the container again you can use [docker start -i](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#start).